# Mouse scroll wheel issues

Tags: xorg, mouse, scrolling

I'm been having issues with the scroll-wheel on my mouse for ages now. I've got a [Silverstone Raven](http://www.silverstonetek.com/raven/products/index.php?model=RVM01&area=en) mouse, and the scrolling action is extremely jerky. If I scroll either up or down, at a natural speed, the scroll action will jerk in the wrong direction almost as much as it goes in the right direction.

I have to scroll almost twice as much to get where I want in a page, and often I'll lose track of where I am because it's not behaving as expected. If I deliberately scroll really slowly, it will go in the correct direction, as expected, but it's really painful.

So, to check that this isn't just a dodgy mouse, I rebooted into Windows - a rare occurrence for me these days - and tried it in there. Scrolling works beautifully; it's really smooth, no glitching, and is a pleasure to use.

Back in Linux-land, the scroll wheel is 'orrible.

In KDE System Settings, I have tried changing the number of lines the mouse wheel scrolls by, but this doesn't affect the glitchiness...

The mouse section of my `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` is as configured by default and looks like:-

```
Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection
```

Anyone have any suggestions how to get my mouse working nicely? I'm on Linux 3.7.6 and this has been an issue for about two years now; I just haven't bothered to tell anyone 'til now..

Comment: I know you won't like this option but: I have a $5 no-name (literally -- there's not a word or symbol on it) usb optical mouse with scroll wheel and everything works great.  I could not, in all honestly, tell the difference between this and some of the logitech things I paid 10-20 times as much for in the past.  BTW *if* you have installed a driver in windows that came with the mouse, then there is your issue: the manufacturer has done something odd and not made it public or provided a driver for other platforms, complain to *them*.

Comment: Yes, you're right. This is a driver issue. Are there no settings I can hack at until it works properly, though?

Comment: If it is that bad, I would think not -- something is not getting interpreted properly and it may be impossible to compensate for.  That looks like a really nice mouse, but also pretty obscure.  Sadly, even though manufacturers often make use of linux in their products (eg, Silverstone uses it with NAS devices), they still regard end-users of linux as corner cases that do not matter.  I am sure they could just pay someone a few $1000 to write a low maintenance, open source linux driver that people could compile for themselves...industry politics I guess :(

Comment: I've reported the problem to Silverstone. Their engineers are all off celebrating Chinese New Year atm, so will get back to me afterwards. I pointed them at the [source code](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~vcs-imports/evdev/master/view/head:/src/emuWheel.c) and explained the problem in terms of Xorg events.. Found a [decent review](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=silverstone_raven&num=3) about the mouse yesterday, where they used `xev` on Linux to see all the detected events. They appeared to have no problems with the scroll wheel, though...

Comment: yeah, +1 on driver issue.  scroll wheels are jerky by the way they are built.
Rolling the wheel sends a series of click-like events to X - it sounds like windows has some driver that is smoothing these events out

Comment: Have you found a solution for this problem? I think I am seeing the same, although I do see it only with *some* window managers/desktop environments: XFCE (and I believe LXDE if I remember correctly). On the same machine (a VirtualBox under Win7) with the same mouse (a cheap A4TECH OP560NU) with Unity (Ubuntu) or Cinnamon (Debian) I don't see this issue. I could start a new question asking for mouse driver differences between these to hunt it down but wanted to check if you have come across something relevant to this topic in the meanwhile.